# Dynamic datatable creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I am having HTTP GET url which return data in JSON in following format:

```js
{
  "columnDefs": [{
    "colIdentifier": "col1",
    "title": "abc"
  },{
    "colIdentifier": "col2",
    "title": "xyz"
  }],
  "data": [{
    "col1": "data1",
    "col2": "data2"
  }]
}
```

I am able to create jQuery dataTable by making jQuery sync get call like this

```
var api_data;
$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });

$.get("/getTableData", {}, function(data, status) {
  api_data = data;
});
$.ajaxSetup({ async: true });
```

And after that I am processing `api_data` to create jQuery dataTable `aoColumnDefs` and aaData properties.

Problem in this approach is that I have to use `$.ajaxSetup({async: false});` to achieve same.

Is there anyway I can use dataTable "fnServerData" attribute to make it async?

Is it possible to get http data in fnServerData function itself and then do something like `$('#dataTable').aoColumnDefs(aoColumnDefs)` in it?

Comment: Synchronous HTTP requests make kittens cry. Why not use DataTables' built in AJAX methods?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan fnServerData attribute is used for datatable async call. question is can we set aoColumnDefs in its callback function to determine column dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make the request synchronous?

I have an app with a load of datatables on various tabs, and if the user switches to a tab for which the data isn't yet loaded, in the tabs activate function, I fire off an async $.ajax request to the server to fetch the data for it.

In the $.ajax invocation, I define a success function, which will be called once the data has been downloaded, which will initialize the datatable after any required processing of the data (I build up a load of custom filters, and do a load of extra processing)

Something like this simplified version:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getTableData",
    data: JSON.stringify({ param1: value1 }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var results = response.d;
        DataTableInit(results);
    },
    failure: function (msg) {
        $('#TableLocation).html("Error: Unable to fetch data: " + msg);
    }
});
```